# 'output' keyword isn't recognized by the syntax highlighter in SQL code blocks

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

The highlighting for SQL code blocks doesn't appear to recognize the keyword 'output'. Please see [Showing column twice in a query, second time showing data post update/set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783673/showing-column-twice-in-a-query-second-time-showing-data-post-update-set/8783738#8783738) for an example. Note that 'output' in the code block isn't colored blue like the other SQL keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is usually the case for issues related to syntax highlighting here, you'll need to take this up with the [Prettify project](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list), which Stack Exchange uses for its code highlighting purposes.

In particular, [this file](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-sql.js) would need to be updated to include the `OUTPUT` keyword. I'd argue that a keyword specific to T-SQL shouldn't be part of the generic SQL highlighter anyway, but there's plenty of dialect-specific keywords in that list already, so it's most likely that it was just overlooked.

You might be able to leave a comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92419/150235) as an alternate route to getting it fixed, as [Mike Samuel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137403/mike-samuel) is the owner of the project.

Comment: Thank-you, I didn't realize this was a common thing (I only did a cursory search before posting). Will see what I can do.